# It there an equivalent to size_t in llvm

Tags: c, llvm, size-t

Some system libraries like malloc strlen want or return size_t as parameter.

- What is the right choice in LLVM IR to interact with these functions?
- Is the selection the task for the compiler?
- Does LLVM IR have a size_t type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the LLVM level, size_t doesn't exist.  It is a construct for the benefit of the developer that is typedef'd to a native type.  The native types have a fixed size for the target architecture and that is how the compiler represents them in LLVM bit code.  So on x86, size_t might by viewed by the front end as unsigned long, which it then writes to LLVM as i32 (since LLVM assembly doesn't have an unsigned type).

Comment: so its the task of the compiler to know the architecture it is compiling for?

Comment: @waynix, Yes, surely. If you need to interact with C/C++ you should know the target you're compiling for - these languages are not target-neutral.

Comment: So what do you use for dynamic arrays where in C you would use `size_t` for # of elements in array?

Answer (score -5):

You can use `size_t` in llvm, it is a valid type to be used as normal.

Comment: The llvm assembler itself does not know size_t.

Comment: You may be referring to Clang (the C compiler). @waynix is correct that there is no such type in LLVM.