# How to you add platform specific function definitions in LLVM pass?

Tags: llvm

I was trying to add a function declaration for something provided by the system.
However, the function prototype returns `size_t`, which is int32 on 32bit platform and int64 on 64bit platform.
I'd like to know if there is a method to detect target platform and add the declaration accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, `LLVM IR` as a target neutral language cannot possibly know target-specific type sizes. Have a look at [this](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2008-May/014290.html) relevant discussion where Chris Lattner comments on the subject. Also, at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825186/it-there-an-equivalent-to-size-t-in-llvm) relevant SO question.

So, this is the job of the front-end and this causes extra bookkeeping information that front-ends need to "know" for a target and its ABI. So, for example, you might have needs for projects like [this](http://loci-lang.org) in the case of the [Loci](http://loci-lang.org) programming language.

Now, specifically for `size_t` according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> [...] `std::size_t` can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in
>   which case it is synonymous with `std::uintptr_t`.

So, you could use the `getIntPtrType` method of [`DataLayout`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html) class.

For any other data types, I'm not sure how far *"guessing"* can get you (probably not very far judging from the previous references).

Lastly, another alternative could be [extending](https://llvm.org/docs/ExtendingLLVM.html#extending-llvm-adding-instructions-intrinsics-types-etc) `LLVM` with a custom intrinsic (see [`memcpy`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-memcpy-intrinsic) for example), which inevitably goes through specific definition per target.

---

<strike>For actually adapting your integer type creation you could use the [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator along with the use of [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits), in order to provide the correct number of bits in the [`getIntNType`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Type.html#acaf8e4c3e40e01e848c1fad5f05b81cd) call.</strike>

This will get you as far as using the right size for integer type on the platform where your module pass is built on.

For detecting a type's size 'dynamically' on the platform where your pass is being run, I know of none other way than providing that info in some sort of configuration file.

However, this can be automated and using the example of various build systems (e.g. [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/) which is also used by `LLVM`), you can craft a simple program that can be compiled and automate that generation.

To that end, and to make this as portable as possible and avoid reinventing the wheel, you can use `cmake`'s [`CheckTypeSize`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/CheckTypeSize.html) module.

Comment: I doubt it's a right answer. The proper solution should involve using TargetMachine or something like that to find out type size.

Comment: @arrowd that is true and I've worked up a solution that includes `llvm::DataLayout`, but the issue persists, since ```size_t``` is not known in LLVM IR and it's replaced away by the front-end at that point.

Comment: I think you should guess it based on the triple or pointer size.

Comment: Cheers. I remember in LLVM DeveloperMeeting 2017 QuarksLab metioned they managed to get "Clangify" working, which is essentially compile extra code with clang. They never mentioned the details. Probably something at the frontend instead of midend then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ZhangHanSheng hmm, I'll have a look into that.

Comment: @compor I figured libClang should be a way to go. However reconstructing clang's arguments at IR level doesn't seem feasible without major modification